# I’m friend with a song

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I’m friend with a song, we both come along,
>   with joy and celebrations
>
> I love my tattoo, my dancing cane too,
>   I speak across all nations
>
> I take part in games, and sometimes in flames,
>   I’m different from all the rest
>
> I see you were brave, I’ll visit your grave,
>   remembered by generations

What is my name?
Hope you like it :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Feels a little bit like a stretch for some of the clues, but are you a...

> flag?

I’m friend with a song, we both come along, with joy and celebrations

> Countries have national flags and anthems, which usually go hand-in-hand for different ceremonies.

I love my tattoo, my dancing cane too, I speak across all nations

> Flags have a pattern or emblem on them, can be waved around ("dance"?) on a stick, and are recognizable to other nations regardless of language.

I take part in games, and sometimes in flames, I’m different from all the rest

> They are displayed by each country at the Olympics, are sometimes burned, and are unique to each nation.

I see you were brave, I’ll visit your grave, remembered by generations

> Soldiers have flags placed on their graves.

Comment: Doesn't seem like much of a stretch, this looks to be a great answer. Maybe the tattoo/dancing part is a bit stretchy, but the rest seems solidly appropriate! Definite +1

Comment: Tattoo could also refer to a bugle call, which then fits perfectly.

Comment: @cobaltduck wow I didnt know about that, it is amazing how you guys know all these things